# Использование LLDB в Visual Studio Code [Windows 10]

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, clang, llvm

Хочу использовать отладчик LLDB в VScode. Проблема заключается в том, что видимо надо указывать конфигурацию в launch.json. Но мои попытки нагуглить правильный шаблон конфигурации не привели к успеху. Через терминал clang и lldb работают как надо. Но я хочу сделать отладку в VScode.
Текущий файл launch.json из VScode:

```
// Используйте IntelliSense, чтобы узнать о возможных атрибутах.
    // Наведите указатель мыши, чтобы просмотреть описания существующих атрибутов.
    // Для получения дополнительной информации посетите: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "cl.exe - Сборка и отладка активного файла",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: cl.exe сборка активного файла"
        }
    ]
}
```

Ошибка при попытки отладки:

```
Visual Studio Code
Выполнение предварительной задачи "С/С++: cl.exe сборка активного файла" завершено с кодом выхода -1.
```

Comment: [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) - это видели?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо за ответ. Не видел, сейчас устанавливаю.

Comment: Прежде чем что-то запускать вам там сначала это нужно собрать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov выбрал необходимый отладчик, но вопрос, есть строка: `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/<your program>"`. Можно ли указать в этом разделе, чтобы отлаживать тот файл, который я хочу, но без изменения `<your program>`. Я так думаю, что этот параметр придется изменять каждый раз для нового файла?